# trying to display file with echo command (with or without quotes)

Tags: unix

So when I try to do

```
echo cat file1.txt
```

The output is **cat file.txt**

However, when I do:

```
echo 'cat file1.txt'
```

The output is the actual contents of the file1.txt

Although I recognize the echo command is not required at all to achieve the goal of displaying the file contents, I was curious as to why the outputs differed in these given situations

Comment: you don't need to type echo just write 'cat file1.txt'

Comment: the question already states what you said. I am trying to learn the behaviour of echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are confused about behaviour

Every unix statment inside  `` is considered as a saparate command

you can directly use `` on command to assign the output of command into that variable

see below:

```
[cloudera@quickstart sub1]$ a=`echo "Hello"`
[cloudera@quickstart sub1]$ echo $a
Hello
[cloudera@quickstart sub1]$
```

in above example you can see i am assigning the output of `echo "Hello"` to a variable named `a`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you typed

```
echo 'cat file.txt'
```

and not

```
echo `cat file.txt`
```

?

In the first case, I have no clue what’s going on. In the second, however, there is no mystery. In most shells, typing

```
foo `bar`
```

means, somewhat (over)simplified, "run bar, and use its output as the command parameters for running foo".

If you are running Bash, this is described in the section on [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution) in the manual.